# Bash: check if repository exists behaves unstable?

Tags: bash, curl, gitlab, repository

### XY-problem

I'm trying to delete a GitLab repository safely, without raising errors. Therefore, I first check if the repository exists, and only delete the repository if it exists. However, I find the behaviour of my check to see if the repository exists, is unstable.

### Code

```
exists=$(git ls-remote --exit-code -h "http://$gitlab_username:$gitlab_server_password@127.0.0.1/$gitlab_username/$repo_name")
echo "exists=$exists"
if [ -z "$exists" ]; then
    echo "Repo does not exist."
else
    output=$(curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Private-Token: $personal_access_token" -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1/api/v4/projects/$gitlab_username%2F$repo_name)
fi
```

### Expected behaviour

If the `exists` variable is empty, I would expect the repository to not exists, because if it would exist, I would expect the `git ls-remote --exit-code -h "http://$gitlab_username:$gitlab_server_password@127.0.0.1/$gitlab_username/$repo_name"` command to recognise it and return:

> exists=7215115a8dee4b99fbb16b5bb4f5ce32a029c595   refs/heads/master

### Observed behaviour

Sometimes when I create a repository named `foobar` in GitLab user `root`, the output of command `git ls-remote --exit-code -h "http://$gitlab_username:$gitlab_server_password@127.0.0.1/$gitlab_username/$repo_name"` is empty, and at other times, it contains:

> exists=7215115a8dee4b99fbb16b5bb4f5ce32a029c595   refs/heads/master

However, when I refresh the browser, and inspect in both cases whether the repository `foobar` exists for GitLab user `root`, the repository exists, even when the `exist` variable is empty.

### Question

How can I reliably determine whether some repository exists in a GitLab server?

### Note

A XY-problem solution might be to delete with a try catch. However, sometimes in testing I go over the deletion limit. That throws an error which would then be caught, allowing the code to move on without having actually deleted the repository. So I do really want to make sure the repository is deleted, possibly with a while loop, deleting until the repository I have determined deleted that the repository is indeed deleted. Hence, I would like to reliably determine whether the repository exists or not.